# Using GCM in iOS without APN permission from user?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to use GCM service without push messaging permission from user? I am implementing an app with chat functionality and GCM works great if users give the permission for push notifications. From [Setting up a GCM Client App on iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client) I understood that there are two complimentary ways of using GCM. Another one is the one where "GCM waits until the client app is in the foreground to send messages with data payloads". However, even this requires that the user has given a permission for push messages.

Is there a way to get foreground notifications through GCM without APN token? Or what else would you suggest to handle situations where user only wants to get instant messages when app is in active use?

**EDIT:** Ok, I finally figured it out. The didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is indeed called if user declines the permission, but only if you also implement "(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler" and add "UIBackgroundModes - remote-notification" to project .plist. I was only implementing the one without the fetchCompletionHandler. This worked fine if user gave permission, but not without. Thank you @user102008 for pointing me to right direction!

Comment: Nothing in the doc you linked to says that the second way requires push notifications. You don't need push notifications to send data to a server, thats just a network request

Comment: From this document I would also assume that you don't need push notifications to send or receive data from GMC. However, to get the gmc token one must always first get an APN token. To my knowlegde, there is no way to generate the gmc token without push notification permission from user?

Comment: There isn't an "APN permission"; since iOS 8 there is a "notification" permission. And it is independent of receiving pushes through APNS. You can send data to your app using APNS that doesn't display a notification, without needing the user's permission. And conversely you need the user's permission to show local notifications that don't come through APNS.

Comment: @user102008 For getting a GCM token, you need to provide it with kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption "that represents the APNS token for the app... This key is required to get a GCM token" (GGLInstanceID.h). However, if the user doesn't approve push notification permission, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is never called. Is there an alternative way to get a APNS token?

Comment: Ok, I finally figured it out. The didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is indeed called if user declines the permission, but only if you also implement  "(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler" and add "UIBackgroundModes - remote-notification" to project .plist. I was only implementing the one without the fetchCompletionHandler. This worked fine if user gave permission, but not without. Thank you @user102008 for pointing me to right direction!